# Looping over a couple of dictionaries within a list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this list :

```
"guests_info": [
              {
                  "title": "Mr.",
                  "first_name": "John",
                  "mi": null,
                  "last_name": "Smith",
                  "suffix": "Sr.",
                  "age": "18+"
              },
              {
                  "title": "Mr.",
                  "first_name": "James",
                  "mi": null,
                  "last_name": "Jones",
                  "suffix": null,
                  "age": "18+"
              }
          ]
```

It´s json. So, What i have to do is to create a body like this one:

```
{

"profile": {
    "name": {
        "title": "Miss",
        "firstName": "Kairi",
        "lastName": "asdasd"
    },
    "age": 8
},
"preferences": {
    "avatarIdentifier": "15655408",
    "favoriteCharacterIdentifier": "15655408"
},
"friendsAndFamily": {
    "groupClassification": {
        "name": "TRAVELLING_PARTY"
    },
    "accessClassification": {
        "name": "PLAN_VIEW_SHARED"
    }
}
```

}

For every guest in the list and do a POST to this url :

```
https://env5.xxx.api.go.com/xxxxx/xxxx/id;swid=" + swid_id + "/managed-guests
```

Some things like `Preferences` is the same for every guest. I have a little xperience with python. I supposed i have to put the `guests_info` inside a for loop and for every dictionay i have to create a new string containing a new body, but i´m not sure how to exactly count how many dictionaries are in `guests_info`.

Any help will be really appreciatted

Comment: Make a function that accepts one guest `dict` and posts to your url (use the `requests` module, very simple). Then just call the function in a loop `for guest in guests_info:`

Comment: @Cfreak yes, good idea. but how can i tell how many guests are? there is no label in the List representig each guest, or the for loop you are suggesting separates every dict as an element of the lis??

Comment: len(guests_info) will give u the count of dictionaries in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Cfreak suggested, just make a function which will appropriately post the data you wish to post. To create that data, what you need to do is to loop over the list, and then over the keys of each dictionary.

E.g.,

```
dict_list = [
        { 'foo' : 'baz',
          'bar' : 'qux'
          },
        { 'foo' : 'qux',
          'bar' : 'baz'
          }
        ]
```

Followed by, at some point

```
for each in dict_list:
    for key in each:
        print(key + ": " + each[key])
```

Just be aware that the data won't be in any particular order. If you need to maintain order, you can manually reference each key.

To determine the length of the list, you can just

`len(dict_list)` which will output `2`

If you want assistance with creating the body of the JSON query, I can certainly help with that.

Comment: my doubt is how to send the dictionary of every guest through the function. The function i have created is this one:

    def post_creation_participants(url, **dicto)

Comment: What specifically are you asking? You can use the requests module to send a dictionary payload directly to a url, you just have to create the appropriate dictionary.